# How to execute sum(a)/sum(b) query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to execute `sum(a)/sum(b)` query in SQL Server?

I have subquery with `a = sum(...)` and `b = count(...)`. I need to calculate `avg(all)` for all records from subquery in the main query. It's `avg(all) = sum(a)/sum(b)`. But SQL Server doesn't permit this expression. How to calculate it? The count of records in the main query can't be changed.

Thanks a lot for the help!

```
select
  sum(a)/sum(b) as avg_x
from
  (
   select
     sum(x) as a,
     count(x) as b
   from
     xyTable
   group by
     y
  )
group by
  <any_columns>
```

The error is:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression 
>   containing an aggregate or a sub query.

Comment: If you run the subquery by itself do you get the correct data out? Also, what's the exact error message?  Please read the [faq] and[ask] before posting.

Comment: All is correct. But sum(a)/sum(b) syntax is permitted by MSSQL.

Comment: Your inner select statement is going to return 1 row with two columns. I'm not sure why you need the outer query at all. Also I'm pretty confident you can just do `SUM(x) / COUNT(x)` or `AVERAGE(x)` in the inner query.

Comment: @diaho actually it will return one row per distinct value of `y`

Comment: @JimGarrison ah - you're absolutely right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum(a)/sum(b)` is acceptable by MSSQL. The issue was on another part of query: `sum(min(a))`.

Comment: Please DELETE this question and repost the correct question then

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
select
 avg(x) as avg_x
from
 xyTable
group by
 y
```

Comment: Query is simplified. Can't do this.

Comment: Then please show us a query that properly illustrates why this is not an option.  We cant help you effectively without knowing the set of constraints that you are operating under.

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris says -- it would help if you posted a representative query.

Short of that, I'll point out that you can avoid the specific error you got by replacing the sub-query in your sample with a table variable / cte / what have you that contains the results of your current sub-query.

I.e.:

```
---create the table variable @myTable
---then SELECT sum(a)/sum(b) from @myTable...
```